# Ansible Tower API not accepting token

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower, ansible-awx

I am performing the following `POST` in a `Tower` server:

```
http://<my-tower-url>/api/v2/job_templates/10/launch/


Headers:
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:sometokenhere
```

And getting back the error:

> {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}

Have also tried the following:

```
Headers:
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Token sometokenhere
```

as suggested [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/auth_token.html).

Same happens when passing raw username/password in the `POST` body as follows (and skipping the `Authorization` header):

```
{
    "username": "myusername",
    "password": "mypass",
    "inventory": "inventoryname",
    "verbosity": 0,
    "extra_vars": {
        "var1": "somevar1",
        "var2": "somevar2",
        "var3": "somevar3",
        "var4": "somevar4",
        "var5": "somevar5"
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: the link says to use the `Authorization: Token xxxxxxxx`, not just `Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxx`. Maybe its just this?

Comment: have also tried this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using basic auth as follows:

**1**.create the user which you want to run your ci jobs with

**2**.perform the following post at the respective CI job:

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -w \"%{http_code}\n\" -X POST http://<my-tower-url>/api/v2/job_templates/10/launch/ \
                  -H \"authorization: Basic $MY_AUTH_TOKEN\" \
                  -H \"content-type: application/json\" \
                  -d \"@awx_data.json
```

Where

- `awx_data.json` is a file holding the actual `POST` body
- `MY_AUTH_TOKEN` is the tyical [`base64`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386112/what-is-base64-clear-text-username-and-password) encoded username+password of the above user

You can also assign the above result and check it against `201` which is what `AWX` returns upon successful job creation.

Polling the `AWX` server to check if the job was successfully finished is another story of course.

Comment: Hey! Could you please post in your answer the equivalent POST request you'd make in say.. Postman?

I'm trying to request a personal token from `/api/v2/users/13/personal_tokens/` but it will only work from the Ansible website. If I try with Postman, sending through the correct username & password in the body, it still says "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Answer (score 1):

```
Authorization: Bearer <oauth2-token-value>
```

[See here](https://www.ansible.com/blog/summary-of-authentication-methods-in-red-hat-ansible-tower), Section "3. OAuth 2 Token Authentication", part "Curl Example".